# Предложения по хедеру в новом дизайне

Tags: предложение, дизайн

Высказал на metaSO несколько предложений по новому дизайну, [который нас тоже ждёт](/q/4804/178988):

- [Подвинуть список других сайтов к логотипу](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/343986/4928642)
- [Очереди проверки не принадлежат пользователю](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343988/review-queues-do-not-belong-there)
- [Подвинуть поле поиска вправо](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/343992/4928642)
- [Увеличить размер логотипа](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/343985/4928642) - касается только SO, на остальных сайтах нет лишних кнопок

+++ [Вопрос на uxSE](//ux.stackexchange.com/q/105047/97304).

Собственно, если сделать по всем эти пунктам, то получится такой порядок:

[image: результат]

Но естественно согласиться можно и не со всеми пунктами.

И на этой картинке важен только порядок, а не значки. Со значками, текстом и другими деталями можно будет разобраться потом.

PS: **Данный вопрос является призывом проголосовать в перечисленных**.

PPS: В вопрос можно добавлять ещё предложения. Ну и ответы постить тоже можно :)

Comment: Так лучше, мне нравится, даже больше, чем привычный нынешний. / Только кнопку **[?]** (help) надо куда-то добавить.

Comment: Судя по голосам для упомянутых предложений особой поддержки не найдено среди пользователей. Ну и кстати, ещё вопрос, когда **нас** ждёт этот дизайн. Я думаю, не раньше, чем документацию завезут. А к тому времени может быть ещё и передизайнят кое-чего.

Comment: @alexolut, ну так я этим вопросом как бы призываю сходить и проголосовать. Полагаю, здесь людям более понятно, зачем переключаться между сайтами (только что дописывал вопрос на эту тему).

Comment: @avp, на так напиши тоже предложение.

Comment: А мне вот нравится то, что в новом дизайне поиск по центру — так ему отводится центральное место. В остальном предложенный вариант поддерживаю.

Comment: @Qwertiy, вот это `As for SO.Meta and the whole of SO.... well, you need to have a thick skin, lots of time to lose and a passion for being trolled. I was a very respected and qualified user there and left it to never get back, so... – Devin 33 mins ago` в одном из комментариев по вашей ссылке на uxSE говорит очень о многом...

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fjmoj.png вот так получается каша, сейчас в so чуточку непривычно, но лаконично и удобно. и тоже соответственно за то чтобы поиск был по центру

Comment: @Elena, каша получается, потому что я просто те же значки переставил, а надо их ещё и поменять. Список сайтов превратить в стрелочку, очередь проверок написать словом Review, количество знаков выстроить в столбик и ещё кучу всего. Я же сказал, смотреть только на последовательность, а не на внешний вид.

Answer (score 3):

Добавить кнопку **[?]** (help) перед полем поиска.

Comment: Эм.. Я имел в виду, задать вопрос на metaSO. А то, если я буду переводить вопросы, меня там забанят - я и так уже 4 однотипных вопроса задал. Кстати, кажется, ещё знаки потерялись.

Comment: @Qwertiy, ну, там же возможно придется на английском что-то пояснять и т.п., а мне это не комфортно.

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/343165/4928642

Comment: @Qwertiy, я понял, они уже обсуждают это.

Comment: Да нет, они уже обсудили... Ссылка в футере.

Comment: @Qwertiy, да и  ладно. В конце-концов, что нам дадут, то и будем есть -)